# apply color scale via php similar to excel conditional formatting

Tags: php, html

Is there something out of the box in PHP to create dynamic color scales similar to the conditional formatting done in excel? Not trying to build a sheet but to display it in HTML in a similar fashion. Currently, I am doing it manually by applying the color based on the values/percentages but I am having a hard time controlling the lightness and darkness of the colors dynamically.

[image: Snapshot of excel color scale]

Comment: Since PHP is a server side language, it doesn't rally have a concept of "colors". You should probably set some `class=""` attributes to the cells and leave the styling to CSS.